# assets location for a sideloaded app on Kindle Fire

Tags: android

I develop an app for android and install it to Kindle Fire by file manager. I would like to check that all the assets are in place (actually, some are loaded at runtime from my site via http).

The problem is - I cannot find the assets on the device when I look for them in file manager/explorer. Do I miss something obvious?

A second, related question. Will the assets be in a different place when the app is downloaded from Amazon after being accepred to Appstore?